# how to use static rendering in Angular 15

Tags: angular

ɵrenderComponent not found in в @angular/core v 15
How can I use this method in @angular/core v 15 ?

```
import { ɵrenderComponent, ɵdetectChanges, ɵLifecycleHooksFeature } from "@angular/core";
import { CompileComponent } from "./compile-component.decorator";
import "./style.css";

@CompileComponent({
  selector: `ivy`,
  template: `
    <h1>
      Hey!  {{ name }} here.
    </h1>
    <button (click)="changeName()">Change Name</button>
    <hr />
    <button (click)="loadDynamicComponent()">Load Dynamic Component</button>
    <br />
  `
})
export class IvyComponent {
  name = `Sidd ‍`;

  changeName() {
    this.name = `Ivy `;
    ɵdetectChanges(this);
  }

  loadDynamicComponent() {
    import('./dynamic.component').then(({DynamicComponent}) => {
      ɵrenderComponent(DynamicComponent, { 
        host: "dynamic",
        hostFeatures: [ ɵLifecycleHooksFeature ]
      });
    });
  }
}
ɵrenderComponent(IvyComponent, { host: "ivy" });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-load-angular-component-lazily-in-ivy-9zmhrx?file=package.json,index.ts

Answer (score 0):

This method is available in `@angular/core` version 13.
In version 15 it is no longer. See also [docs for ivy ɵrenderComponent · Issue #34856 · angular/angular · GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34856).

[image: stackblitz example]

Comment: Please embed images (putting an exclamation mark in front of the link), or better: add a link to your stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful using `ɵ` functions they are named like that due to they are not public api and is bound to change. Not only can these components change in name and functionality, but they are also mostly undocumented, so you will gain little to no support using it.

If you want to dynamically render a component use the official way to do it to avoid support issues in the future.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader